# best way to capture R output into latex table

Tags: tables, r

I am running a bunch of models in R using the `caret` package. This package is an interface to many modeling techniques and methodologies.

There are certain output of each model I'd like to convert to Latex code but I am looking for some sort of automatic program or template to make it look pretty. I was hoping for one letter sized page per model. Here are the two main outputs from the R program

```
 Call:
NULL

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-0.0552  -0.0508  -0.0508  -0.0508   3.6831  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error  z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -6.65336    0.02520 -264.020   <2e-16 ***
H3K27me3    -0.12830    0.11265   -1.139   0.2547    
H3K36me3     0.16695    0.07527    2.218   0.0266 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 28404  on 1427599  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 28397  on 1427597  degrees of freedom
AIC: 28403

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 9
```

and

```
Generalized Linear Model 

1427600 samples
     12 predictor
      2 classes: 'nbp', 'bp' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 10 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 1284840, 1284839, 1284840, 1284840, 1284840, 1284840, ... 
Resampling results

  ROC        Sens  Spec  ROC SD      Sens SD  Spec SD
  0.4896863  1     0     0.01090207  0        0
```

I particularly like the R output's formatting and was wondering if there is a way to copy this layout in latex (or another layout that's feasible).

*if all of the above information doesn't fit 1 A4 page, there is information I can take out that I don't really need for my results.

I am aware of the `stargazer` R package however, it doesn't look like its compatible with the `caret` modeling package.

Comment: This isn't a TeX-based solution, but this sounds a lot like the literate programming workflow that org-babel provides, which works very well in my experience. Can you provide a screenshot of R's table format? I'm sure it's possible, but I'm *not* sure it's actually desirable.

Comment: What is R's table format? Do you mean how the `caret` object is stored internally within R?

Comment: You should e-mail the author of stargazer and make a request. He keeps implementing new support for R packages based on users' input, cf. the [ChangeLog](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/ChangeLog).

Comment: "I particularly like the R output's formatting and was wondering if there is a way to copy this layout in latex (or another layout that's feasible)." Of course not the internal representation -- that's R's business to know :)

Comment: I think the alternative would be to just write down the information in excel and format it the way I want, then use a excel - to - latex conversion